# Edit a record displayed as a table row in Ruby on Rails (3.1.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails and have been learning it on my own. This is also the first time I am posting on Stackoverflow although I refer to it a lot. Below is the snippet of the ERB code that's displaying the records of a model called Ideas:

```
<% @idea.each do |i| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= i.name %></td>
    <td><%= i.description %></td>
    <td><a class="btn" href="share"><i class="icon-share"></i></a></td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to(ideas_edit_path(@i), :class => 'btn') do %>
             <i class="icon icon-edit"> </i>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><a class="btn" href="destroy"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Each row contains "Name", "Description" followed by icons called "share", "edit", "destroy". I want to display a form for each of these actions for that particular record. I don't know how to pass the id of the record to these actions. Can somebody please point me in the right direction? I think I have the routes defined correctly because I can type in the full ERL (/ideas/2/edit) and it brings up the edit form.

Answer (score 0):

Change your @idea to @ideas to reflect that it is a collection.

The set that you iterate over should be something like

```
@ideas.each do |idea|
  link_to(edit_idea_path(idea), :class => 'btn') 
end
```

So your link is now to `edit_idea_path(idea)`

The form file will be in `app/view/ideas` called `edit.html.erb`
Actually the form is shared by the new and edit actions so the best idea is to have `_form.html.erb` and include that in both the new and edit forms.

Code in the .erb template will be like

```
form_for @idea do |f|
  various input fields
end
```

I would recommend that you quickly try to create another app using the scaffolding that's available in rails.  Then look at what gets generated and you'll be better informed about what things should be named, where they are, etc.
This might sounds a bit drastic, but really it's as simple as:

```
$ cd ~          # Go to root
$ mkdir newapp  # Create a new directory
$ cd newapp     # Create a new rails app
$ rails generate scaffold Idea name:string description:text  # Use scaffolding
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the named routes (i.e. `ideas_edit_path`), you can just pass a model object in as an argument, and they'll build the correct route for that object.  There's a bug in your code above where you're referring to `@i` when it should be `i` (the local variable declared in the loop above it).

Another minor nit: you probably want to use `@ideas` rather than `@idea` for the collection to indicate that it's a collection, but that's not necessarily a bug in itself.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I am getting the id correctly now. I will fix the pluralization convention that you had suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `link_to` helper with a `do` to build a block.

```
<%= link_to edit_idea_path(i), class: "btn" do %>
  <i class="icon icon-edit"></i>
<% end %>
```

Looks like your using the Bootstrap framework with Rails -- very nice combination!